# Class not found error when attempting to publish kyslik/column-sortable package

Tags: laravel-9

When i attempt to publish kyslik/column-sortable package with the command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="KyslikColumnSortableColumnSortableServiceProvider" --tag="config"
```

I get the error

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
                                                                   
Class "KyslikColumnSortableColumnSortableServiceProvider" not found
```

following instructions from https://meritocracy.is/blog/2020/04/17/laravel-using-pagination-sorting-and-filtering-with-your-tables/

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue when following those instructions.  It looks like there's a typo in two parts.

In config/app.php there needs to be some back slashes to properly identify the provider class.  Use this instead:
Kyslik\ColumnSortable\ColumnSortableServiceProvider::class,

And same thing when running the php artisan command:
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Kyslik\ColumnSortable\ColumnSortableServiceProvider" --tag="config"

That fixed the issue for me.  I haven't made it further in the instructions yet to see if anything else needs to be adjsuted.  I found the correct commands on these instructions: https://www.laravelia.com/post/laravel-9-table-sorting-example-with-pagination